# Error when trying to connect to a BLE device using bluepy

Tags: python, bluetooth-lowenergy, raspberry-pi4

I'm trying to connect to a BLE device using Raspberry PI4 model B and subscribe to the characteristics, but every time the script fails with an error. I`m tried to change adrr type to "public" but it didn`t work.

```
  File "/home/user/worksPy/notification.py", line 8, in <module>
    dev = btle.Peripheral(MAC, "random", 1)
          ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/dist-packages/bluepy-1.3.0-py3.11.egg/bluepy/btle.py", line 411, in __init__
    self._connect(deviceAddr, addrType, iface, timeout)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/dist-packages/bluepy-1.3.0-py3.11.egg/bluepy/btle.py", line 467, in _connect
    raise BTLEDisconnectError("Failed to connect to peripheral %s, addr type: %s"
bluepy.btle.BTLEDisconnectError: Failed to connect to peripheral c3:77:69:80:ee:e0, addr type: random
```

A Google search turns up nothing about this error, or the solutions don’t work for me. Also I didn't find an answer to this error here.

```
from bluepy import btle

MAC = "c3:77:69:80:ee:e0"
SERVICE_UUID = "000054fe-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb"
CHARACTERISTIC_UUID = "00002A00-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb"

print("Connect to:" + MAC)
dev = btle.Peripheral(MAC, "random", 1)

print("\n--- dev ----------------------------")
print(type(dev))
print(dev)

print("\n--- dev.services -------------------")
for svc in dev.services:
    print(str(svc))

print("\n------------------------------------")
print("Get Serice By UUID: " + SERVICE_UUID)
service_uuid = btle.UUID(SERVICE_UUID)
service = dev.getServiceByUUID(service_uuid)

print(service)
print("\n--- service.getCharacteristics() ---")
print(type(service.getCharacteristics()))
print(service.getCharacteristics())

#----------------------------------------------
characteristics = dev.getCharacteristics()
print("\n--- dev.getCharacteristics() -------")
print(type(characteristics))
print(characteristics)

for char in characteristics:
    print("----------")
    print(type(char))
    print(char)
    print(char.uuid)
    if(char.uuid == CHARACTERISTIC_UUID ):
        print("=== !CHARACTERISTIC_UUID matched! ==")
        print(char)
        print(dir(char))
        print(char.getDescriptors)
        print(char.propNames)
        print(char.properties)
        print(type(char.read()))
        print(char.read())
```